# Unable to install wordpress plugins on google app engine

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

[image] Even i changed file permissions to 777 of wp-content nothing happened, i am not able to install wordpress plugins...

Comment: set permission for plugins folder to 755 and wp-content to 755 as well. It should work.

Comment: @Usman Not working..... i have changed permissions of plugins folder to 755,even of wp-admin, wp-includes also but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the plugins on your local instance and then re-deploy to App Engine as mentioned on [this](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible#updating_wordpress_plugins_and_themes) document.

This is also explained other tutorials such as [this one](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard), the reason for this is basically that the directories for WP are read only by default on App Engine, and since it's a managed service, you don't really have much control on the folder permissions.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: sorry for my stupidity but i must ask - I dont know how to open local instance in app engine. I mean do i have to type url 127.0.0.1 on my address bar. Or do i have to type commands in cloud shell as given in the docs provided by u.

Comment: By local instance I mean the instance from which you deployed wordpress to App Engine. Did you use your personal machine, or did you deployed it from Cloud Shell?

Comment: I have created my website on Flywheel 's Local environment on my PC then i installed a fresh wordpress on app engine standard environment. my strategy was to use all in one WP migaration plugin to transfer my website files ....but since i can not install any plugin it all screwed up...